# CMAKE: How do I install executable along with required dylib to custom directory?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, installation, dylib

So I'm using CMake to build a C++ project (on Mac OS) and my project relies on a dylib (I'm using TBB https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/ but the specific library itself doesn't matter)

If I do a standard "cmake" and "make" it builds the executable where I want it and when I run my app, the dylib links correctly and everything works perfectly.

The problem comes in when I try to do a "make install" and try to run the resulting executable from the install directory. I get an "image not found" error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libtbb.dylib
Referenced from: 
/Users/MyName/Desktop/ProjectRoot/install/./MyApp
Reason: image not found
```

Interestingly, if I do a regular "make" without an install, and then manually copy over the executable to the install directory, then that *will* link against my dylib properly. I have no idea why that is.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
Root 
    CMakeLists.txt 
    Source/ 
    Libraries/ 
        tbb/ 
            include/ 
            lib/ 
                libtbb.dylib
    install/
```

...and my CMakeLists.txt file is below:

```
# Start of CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project (MyApp)

# Set C++ version and output paths
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 1)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/install")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")

# Find TBB
find_library (
    TBB_LIBRARIES
    NAMES tbb libtbb # what to look for
    HINTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Libraries/tbb/lib" # where to look
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH # do not search system default paths
)

# Set Custom Include Files + TBB header files 
include_directories(Source/Headers Libraries/tbb/include)


# Set Source Files
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES "Source/*.cpp")
add_executable(MyApp ${SRC_FILES})

# Link Libraries 
target_link_libraries(MyApp ${TBB_LIBRARIES})

# Set compile flags
set_target_properties(MyApp PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 14) #LINK_FLAGS "-Wl")
target_compile_features(MyApp PUBLIC cxx_std_14)

# Install executable
install(TARGETS MyApp DESTINATION .)
```

If I try to also add the following line, and install the dylib as well:

```
install(TARGETS ${TBB_LIBRARIES} DESTINATION lib)
```

then when I do a "make install" I get the following error instead:

```
install TARGETS given target 
"/Users/MyName/Desktop/ProjectRoot/Libraries/tbb/lib/libtbb.dylib"
which does not exist in this directory.
```

So I just can't seem to get this install to work. How do I fix it so that both my executable and my library get installed in the right place and that my executable will be able to link against my library when run?

Comment: The first error message is about `tbb` isn't under RPATH for your application. If you want to copy that library on "install" step, use `install(FILES)` command flow: command `install(TARGETS)` is only for targets *built by your project*. Also, CMake provides [Bundle Utilities](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/BundleUtilities.html), which can be used for copy libraries near your application.

Comment: Try to add install (FILES TBB_LIBRARIES_LIBS DESTINATION lib) where TBB_LIBRARIES_LIBS is what find_library returns

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you very much! That worked for me =)

Comment: @Cristi Thank you very much as well!